# Conversion of conventional matrix to Sparse Matrix in JAVA

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am trying to execute the code which takes input from the user and first converts those elements into conventional matrix and then converts it into sparse matrix

```java
import java.util.*;

public class SparseMatrix {

    static void enterMatrix(int matrix[][], Scanner sc) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; ++j) {
                matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    static void displayMatrix(int[][] mat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + mat[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static int checkSparseMatrix(int[][] mat) {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != 0)
                    cnt++;
            }
        }
        return (cnt);
    }

    static void sparseMatrixDisplay(int[][] mat, int cnt) {
        int Spmatrix[][] = new int[cnt][3];
        int a, b, c;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mat[0].length; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != 0) {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    c = mat[i][j];
                    Spmatrix[k][0] = a;
                    Spmatrix[k][1] = b;
                    Spmatrix[k][2] = c;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nElements of Sparse matrix are :");
        for (int i = 0; i < Spmatrix.length; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.print("\t" + Spmatrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice;
        System.out.println("Enter the rows and columns of matrix:");
        int row = sc.nextInt();
        int col = sc.nextInt();
        int mat[][] = new int[row][col];
        do {
            System.out.println("\n1. Enter Matrix");
            System.out.println("2. Display Matrix");
            System.out.println("3. Display Sparse matrix");
            System.out.println("4. Exit");

            System.out.println("Enter your choice :");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter the matrix elements:");
                    enterMatrix(mat, sc);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("The Entered Matrix is:");
                    displayMatrix(mat);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    int cnt = checkSparseMatrix(mat);
                    System.out.println("The count is " + cnt);
                    if (cnt < ((row * col) / 2)) {
                        System.out.println("The entered matrix is a sparse matrix ");
                        sparseMatrixDisplay(mat, cnt);
                    } else
                        System.out.println("The entered matrix is not a sparse matrix ");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Exiting the Menu.....");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Enter the correct choice");
                    break;
            }

        } while (choice != 4);

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

But i am facing problem in the loop where matrix gets converted into sparse matrix in the nested for loops. After running the program it does execute the loop but does not display the sparse matrix can you help me with it?

Comment: Thanks for the question, but after running the program, the sparse matrix could be displayed successfully on my occasions. First, I enter the rows and the columns, say 3x3. Then, I enter a group of numbers that contain 3 non-zero integers, 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 2. Next, I enter choice 3, which means printing the sparse matrix onto the screen and the elements can be seen in the format "row + col + number". However, you said that the sparse matrix could not be displayed. Could you please provide your examples?

Comment: You may use C-style array type declarations, like `int matrix[][]`. However, it is always recommended to use Java-style array type declarations `int[][] matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

On my occasions, the sparse matrix can be displayed successfully as I said in the comments.

Additionally, the method `sparseMatrixDisplay` returns nothing and only provides the function that prints the non-zero elements. But it could be more memory-saving if it prints a line immediately after finding such an element, instead of saving the intermediate result into an array which is useless after the return of the method and printing them together.

```java
static void sparseMatrixDisplay(int[][] matrix) {
    System.out.println("\nElements of Sparse matrix are:");
    int rowCount = matrix.length, colCount = matrix[0].length;
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colCount; ++j) {
            if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                System.out.printf("\t%d\t%d\t%d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

p.s. You might use C-style array type declarations, like `int matrix[][]`. However, it is recommended to use Java-style array type declarations `int[][] matrix`.